# Conditional Statements on IE browser check

Tags: html, css, browser, conditional-comments

I have the following code to display a certain UL while in IE7. How can I then apply the other UL style for all browsers except IE7? for example to chrome, firefox, and IE8 - IE10

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
        <ul class="toggle" style="margin-right:30px; list-style:none">
          @if (Model.CourseSections != null)
          {
            foreach (var sectionItem in Model.CourseSections)
            {                     
              <li>
                <h5 class="accordion-title">@sectionItem.Title<span class="accordion-icon"></span></h5>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <ul>
                    @foreach (var subSectionItem in sectionItem.SectionContents)
                    {
                      <li><a href="#" id="menuItem @subSectionItem.ContentID @sectionItem.CourseSectionID" onclick="SubItemMenu(id)">@subSectionItem.Content.Name</a></li> 
                    }
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            }
          }
        </ul>
        <![endif]-->

        <ul class="toggle" style="list-style:none">
          @if (Model.CourseSections != null)
          {
            foreach (var sectionItem in Model.CourseSections)
            {                     
              <li>
                <h5 class="accordion-title">@sectionItem.Title<span class="accordion-icon"></span></h5>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                  <ul>
                  @foreach (var subSectionItem in sectionItem.SectionContents)
                  {
                    <li><a href="#" id="menuItem @subSectionItem.ContentID @sectionItem.CourseSectionID" onclick="SubItemMenu(id)">@subSectionItem.Content.Name</a></li> 
                  }
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            }
          }
        </ul>
```

Comment: What's the difference between these two blocks of code? If it's just the style on the `<ul>` element, then you should find a different solution; you can send the same HTML, but just have a conditional stylesheet for it if you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the difference is just in the styling you could use the conditional comments at the start of the page to set a class on the actual html element. ([Thanks Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>...
```

and then just modify the stylesheet appropriately:

```
.toggle {list-style:none}
.lt-ie8 .toggle {margin-right:30px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
   You're using IE!
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE 7]>
   You're using something else!
<![endif]-->
```

The documentation for IE Conditional Comments can be found here:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments

As @spudley said in the comments, if the only difference is the `style` in the `ul` then this is not the best solution for you.

Comment: Note that while the syntax works in IE, it's invalid - refer to the links given in your answer and the comment for syntax that will validate.

Answer (score 1):

Different markup for different browsers is terrible. If you need conditional styling, then go for [this trick](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) (instead of the opening `<html>`):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

and use it in your styles:

```
something {
    // styling for all browsers
}

.lt-ie9 something { 
    // styling for IE8 and below
}
```

(HTML5Boilerplate has been using something like this, but they [dropped it](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1290) recently.)

This, of course, won't save you if you *really* need browser-conditional markup (not just styling), but then I'd say your actual problem is *"how to do X without resorting to browser-conditional markup"*.